# Apache2 is not starting in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, server, apache2, wine, playonlinux

I'm facing problem with Ubuntu 20.04, I have been trying install PlayOnLinux after installing WINE. When installing PlayOnLinux by command I've removed some dependencies which I have forgotten.

I've also removed Apache by the command `whereis apache2` and found some directories and deleted those using `sudo rm -rf <all directory which found before command (whereis apache2)>`

After that I've tried running apache2 but faced a problem. I removed apache2 and PHP after that I reinstalled apache2 then same problem written below.

- **1st Command:**

```
asifulmamun@asifulmamun-ubuntu:~$ service apache2 start
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

- **2nd Command:**

```
asifulmamun@asifulmamun-ubuntu:~$ systemctl status apache2.service
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
        Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
        Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-11-13 16:36:15 +06; 26s ago
        Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
        Process: 3522 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=126)
Nov 13 16:36:15 asifulmamun-ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Nov 13 16:36:15 asifulmamun-ubuntu apachectl[3535]: /usr/sbin/apachectl: 174: /usr/sbin/apache2: Permission >
Nov 13 16:36:15 asifulmamun-ubuntu apachectl[3522]: Action 'start' failed.
Nov 13 16:36:15 asifulmamun-ubuntu apachectl[3522]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Nov 13 16:36:15 asifulmamun-ubuntu systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=>
Nov 13 16:36:15 asifulmamun-ubuntu systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 13 16:36:15 asifulmamun-ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

- **3rd Command:**

```
asifulmamun@asifulmamun-ubuntu:~$ journalctl -xe
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit apache2.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
   Nov 13 17:46:37 asifulmamun-ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: A start job for unit apache2.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit apache2.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 2312 and the job result is failed.
Nov 13 17:46:37 asifulmamun-ubuntu sudo[77289]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Nov 13 17:46:41 asifulmamun-ubuntu wpa_supplicant[876]: wlp2s0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with 7c:8b:ca:7>
Nov 13 17:46:44 asifulmamun-ubuntu wpa_supplicant[876]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT typ>
Nov 13 17:46:57 asifulmamun-ubuntu wpa_supplicant[876]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS
Nov 13 17:49:31 asifulmamun-ubuntu wpa_supplicant[876]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS
Nov 13 17:49:38 asifulmamun-ubuntu wpa_supplicant[876]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS
Nov 13 17:49:41 asifulmamun-ubuntu wpa_supplicant[876]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS
Nov 13 17:49:46 asifulmamun-ubuntu wpa_supplicant[876]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS
Nov 13 17:49:49 asifulmamun-ubuntu wpa_supplicant[876]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS
Nov 13 17:49:51 asifulmamun-ubuntu wpa_supplicant[876]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS
Nov 13 17:50:10 asifulmamun-ubuntu wpa_supplicant[876]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS
```

What is the solution right now?

Comment: Look in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.

Comment: Nothing to here I was deleted when search with command ```wheris apache2``` and deleted all of location which was found with this command. So all is clear and re-installed them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally it's discouraged to manually uninstall software like Apache that's installed using the package manager. The best thing to do would be to uninstall and purge apache2, then reinstall it if needed. Make sure you backup any config files before doing this.

```
sudo apt-get remove apache2
sudo apt-get purge apache2
```

Then it can be installed once again.

Comment: Thanks I've followed your process and getting error ```/var/www/html``` was not deleting. Then I've delete this file with ```sudo rm -rf /var/www/html```. Then again remove all ``` and install again apache2 and apache2-bin. Now, all is ok, Thank You So much, If i was see carefully this notice '**folder** was not deleting'. I had been can do this. But, see after posting question at askubuntu. But, now feeling better, Thank You @nbailey

Comment: Sorry This command was ```sudo rm -rf /var/www``` and also new some command when facing same problem then try those command for remove-reinstall lot of dependencies: https://github.com/asifulmamun/share-code/blob/master/Apache2-and-PHP-problem-Ubuntu20-mainly-for-APACHE2.txt